Can you cache data indefinetly for offline use in a PWA?
I am trying to figure out if I need to build a native app or if a PWA could work for this idea that I have.
I basically want to store map tiles (let's say from Maptiler) as well as GeoJSON data and display that on a map inside my app. The app would need to work offline 100% of the time and I am unsure if caching data forever is a viable solution?
One of my concerns is let's say a user installs the app, then uses it for the first time. That's fine since he had network access when installing and the data was cached when he opened the app. However, he uses the app again a month later and, when he does, doesn't have network access. Is the data still cached, or is the app now unusable/useless?
